# Как я могу поменять цвет и положение моей кнопки?

Tags: javascript

Имеется такой код, что и куда нужно написать в этот код, что-бы изменить цвет и положение кнопочки? Как применить стиль к этой кнопке?:)

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.type = 'button';
    button.innerHTML = 'Press me';
    button.className = 'btn-styled';
 
    button.onclick = function() {
        // …
    };
 
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    container.appendChild(button);
}, false);
```

Comment: назначайте стили классу `btn-styled`

Comment: ZxNuClear, знал бы как не задавал бы вопроса. Я понятия не имею что и как и куда:)

Comment: в css напишите .btn-styled{тут стили}

Comment: или через тот же javascript : button.style.cssText = "тут стили";

Comment: `button.style.cssText = "color: red; transform: translateX(100px)";` вот так

Comment: Monkey Mutant, спасибо большое, это то что надо. Вот если бы ещё всплываюлюю подсказку туда добавить было бы полное счастье:)

Answer (score 2):

Достаточно иметь *CSS* файл где будет прописан стиль для указанного класса:

```
.btn-styled {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 24px;
    border: 4px solid red;    
}
```

Сам *CSS* файл должен подключаться в html странице

```
<link href="путь/до/файла/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link